# Combine columns based on partial column names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

| date | paris_price | temperature_paris_weather | lyon_price | temperature_lyon_weather |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | -4.2 | 3.0 | -3.8 | 3.2 |
| 2023-01-02 | -5.04 | 2.8 | -3.8 | 3.2 |

I'd like to combine all columns ending with `price`, but I want to keep the associated `temperature`. I don't need the date column. The dataframe should look like this:

| price | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| -4.2 | 3.0 |
| -3.8 | 3.2 |
| -5.04 | 2.8 |
| -3.8 | 3.2 |

How do I do this?

Comment: Are the non-price columns always in the format: 'temperature_city_weather'? If not, how does it generalize?

Comment: @mozway non-price columns all generalize differently. Some are 'temperature_city_weather', others are 'precipitationCity_weather', 'windspeed_10mCity_weather', 'windspeed_100mCity_weather', etc.

Comment: so in this case you would like one column for each of precipitation/windspeed/temperature?

Comment: Yeap. To be honest they don't all have to be in the same df, I just wanted to know how to combine columns that share a naming convention

Comment: You have to extract the city name somehow. to be able to match the columns. I've shown an example below that should be generic enough to work with your described cases. Could you [edit] the question to add a more complete example with a few other columns for completeness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution, based on [`numpy.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:,1:].values.reshape(-1,2), columns=['price', 'temperature'])
```

---

In case the columns are not conveniently sorted, use:

```
cols = [x for x in df.columns if ('_price' in x) or ('_weather' in x)]
half_len = len(cols) // 2
df = df.loc[:, sum(zip(cols[:half_len], cols[half_len:]),())]
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,2), columns=['price', 'temperature'])
```

---

Output:

```
   price  temperature
0  -4.20          3.0
1  -3.80          3.2
2  -5.04          2.8
3  -3.80          3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your column naming convention, a simple way to achieve this would be to isolate the temp and price columns and then use `pd.concat`. You might need another column in your output for city.

```
temp_cols = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('temperature')]
price_cols = [x for x in df.columns if x.endswith('price')]

df_temp = pd.concat([df[col] for col in temp_cols])
df_price = pd.concat([df[col] for col in price_cols])

df_out = pd.concat([df_price, df_temp], axis=1).sort_index()
df_out.columns = ['price', 'temperature']
df_out
```

Output:

| price | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| -4.2 | 3 |
| -3.8 | 3.2 |
| -5.04 | 2.8 |
| -3.8 | 3.2 |

Comment: I believe this assumes that the columns are already sorted by pairs? This would break if not.

Comment: @mozway yes that what I meant by "Based on your column naming convention". Otherwise your general solution is apt

Answer (score 0):

For a generic automated solution (works with an arbitrary number of cities and number of other columns), only relying the word that is before `_price`, you can extract the cities, then find them in all columns with a regex and reshape based on that with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
import re

cities = df.columns.str.extract('(.*)_price', expand=False).dropna()

pat = '|'.join(map(re.escape, cities))

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
       [df.columns.str.extract(fr'({pat})', expand=False),
        df.columns.str.replace(fr'({pat})_?', '', regex=True),
       ])

out = (df.set_axis(idx, axis=1)
         .drop(columns=np.nan, level=0)
         .stack(0).reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

Output:

```
   price  temperature_weather
0  -3.80                  3.2
1  -4.20                  3.0
2  -3.80                  3.2
3  -5.04                  2.8
```

How it works:

```
# find the cities
cities = df.columns.str.extract('(.*)_price', expand=False).dropna()
# Index(['paris', 'lyon'], dtype='object')

# craft a regex
pat = '|'.join(map(re.escape, cities))
# 'paris|lyon'

# extract the cities and rest of string without cities
df.columns.str.extract(fr'({pat})', expand=False)
# Index([nan, 'paris', 'paris', 'lyon', 'lyon'], dtype='object')
df.columns.str.replace(fr'({pat})_?', '', regex=True)
# Index(['date', 'price', 'temperature_weather', 'price', 'temperature_weather'], dtype='object')

# use this to craft a MultiIndex
df.set_axis(idx, axis=1)
#           NaN paris                      lyon                    
#          date price temperature_weather price temperature_weather
# 0  2023-01-01 -4.20                 3.0  -3.8                 3.2
# 1  2023-01-02 -5.04                 2.8  -3.8                 3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to iterate through the DataFrame columns and extract the `price` and `temperature` columns for each city. Something like:

```py
result_data = {'price': [], 'temperature': []}

for col in df.columns:
    if col.endswith('_price'):
        city_prefix = col[:-6] 
        temp_col = f"temperature_{city_prefix}_weather"
        result_data['price'].extend(df[col].tolist())
        result_data['temperature'].extend(df[temp_col].tolist())

result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_data)
```

Output:

```
   price  temperature
0  -4.20          3.0
1  -5.04          2.8
2  -3.80          3.2
3  -3.80          3.2
```

*[CODE DEMO](https://replit.com/@msankrit/UnhappyJuicyTag#main.py)*

**Another Way:**

I can think of one more way to achieve the above result. Thought to add it. You can give it a try as well.

1. Split my original `df` into 2 based on **price-related columns** and **temperature-related columns**.

   ```
   df_price = df.filter(regex='_price$')
   df_temp = df.filter(regex='_weather$')
   ```
2. Reshape each `df` using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) function.

   ```
   df_price = df_price.melt(var_name='city', value_name='price')
   df_temp = df_temp.melt(var_name='city', value_name='temperature')
   ```
3. Concatenate the above two `df` along column axis.

   ```
   result_df = pd.concat([df_price['price'], df_temp['temperature']], axis=1)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot_longer), where for this use case, you pass a dictionary pairing the new column name with a regex - all columns that match the regex will be paired under the new column name:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd 
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(index=None, 
                names_pattern = {'price':'price', 'temperature':'temperature'})
   price  temperature
0  -4.20          3.0
1  -5.04          2.8
2  -3.80          3.2
3  -3.80          3.2
```

This works well because your data has an order to it (`price` followed by `temperature`) and is unique.

If you are unsure about the order of your columns, there are two options for a safer outcome:

- option 1 is to reshape the columns and then use `pivot_longer` to get the final output, using the `.value` placeholder:

```py
temp = df[:] # mutation is on the columns, so it is safe to do a slice.
temp.columns = np.where(temp.columns.str.contains('temperature'),                              
                        temp.columns
                            .str.split("_")
                            .str[::-1].str.join('_'), 
                        temp.columns)
(df
.pivot_longer(
    index='date', 
    names_pattern = r'.+(price|temperature)', 
    names_to = '.value')
.drop(columns='date'))
   price  temperature
0  -4.20          3.0
1  -5.04          2.8
2  -3.80          3.2
3  -3.80          3.2
```

option 2 - another safe bet would be to do some transformations on the columns, and concat, similar to what @mozway does - for this you do not need `pivot_longer`:

```py
temp = df.filter(like='_')
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split('(price|temperature)', expand=True)
out = [temp.xs(axis=1,key=val, level=1)
           .melt(value_name=val)[val] 
       for val in ['price','temperature']]
pd.concat(out,axis=1)

   price  temperature
0  -4.20          3.0
1  -5.04          2.8
2  -3.80          3.2
3  -3.80          3.2
```